# Scan files in a directory to get the number of methods and PHP classes in a directory

Tags: php

Im trying to get the number of class and methods in a specific directory which contain sub folder and scan through them. So far I can only count the number of files.

```
$ite=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("scanME");

//keyword search
$classWords = array('class');
$functionWords = array('function');

//Global Counts
$bytestotal=0;
$nbfiles=0;
$classCount = 0;
$methodCount = 0;

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename=>$cur) {
    $filesize=$cur->getSize();
    $bytestotal+=$filesize;
    if(is_file($cur)) 
    {   
        $nbfiles++;
        foreach ($classWords as $classWord) {
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($cur);
            $place = strpos($fileContents, $classWord);
            if (!empty($place)) { 
                $classCount++;
            } 
        }

        foreach($functionWords as $functionWord) {
            $fileContents = file_get_contents($cur);
            $place = strpos($fileContents, $functionWord);
            if (!empty($place)) { 
                $methodCount++;
            } 
        }

    }

}
```

EDIT: I manage to count the keyword class and function but the problem is it only concatenate for each file. Eg: I have 2 class in one file it will just count 1. How do I count for each keyword in a file?

Comment: What about files that have more than one class?  How accurate do you need this?  While your use of strpos's result this time will work because of the `<?php`, be careful with functions that return indexes, strpos could return a successful result of 0.

Comment: That would count as well. I dont know for sure if strpos works Im having trouble with file_get_contents since what im tring to search for is a folder not just a specific file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using token instead of keyword is the better solution for this

```
$bytestotal=0;
$nbfiles=0;
$fileToString;
$token;
$pathInfo;


$classCount = 0;
$methodCount = 0;


foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename=>$cur) {
    $filesize=$cur->getSize();
    $bytestotal+=$filesize;
    if(is_file($cur)) 
    {   
        $nbfiles++;
        $fileToString = file_get_contents($cur);
        $token = token_get_all($fileToString);
        $tokenCount = count($token);

        //Class Count
        $pathInfo = pathinfo($cur);
        if ($pathInfo['extension'] === 'php') {
            for ($i = 2; $i < $tokenCount; $i++) {
                if ($token[$i-2][0] === T_CLASS && $token[$i-1][0] === T_WHITESPACE && $token[$i][0] === T_STRING ) {
                $classCount++;
                }
            }
        } else {
            error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        }

        //Method Count 

        for ($i = 2; $i < $tokenCount; $i++) {
            if ($token[$i-2][0] === T_FUNCTION && $token[$i-1][0] === T_WHITESPACE && $token[$i][0] === T_STRING) {
                $methodCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you define $classContents is at the top where you're attempting to get the contents of the directory:

```
$classContents = file_get_contents('scanMeDir');
```

You should be getting the contents of each file while looping through the RecursiveDirectoryIterator results.  (You also don't need to create a new iterator instance):

```
foreach ($ite as $filename => $cur) {
    $classContents = file_get_contents($filename);
    ...
}
```